Windows fatal exception: code 0xc000001d, Spyder, Matplotlib
While trying to use Matplotlib tools for plotting, the Windows fatal exception: code 0xc000001d error appears in my IDE. My environment Python version is 3.9.19, but I guess I 've tried more updated as well- 3.11.5. My Spyder Python version is 3.11.
Tried to remove - reinstalled, created new environment but all was in vain: few times it helped temporarily, but the problem always reappeared.
I was wondering if somebody have had similar issues...

we need more information. how did you set up the environment.  is this windows? sounds like it. thats a more important tag likely than spyder.

Do you get the same error if you run the code from a command line, without using Spyder?

Well, hope I get it correctly. I work in Windows 11, my environments are made by conda create command: conda create -n may2024 python=3.9.0 matplotlib pandas numpy          ( where may2024 is my env name) . All packages are installed by conda.
As for running the code from the command line, I haven't really tried this option as I was unaware of it. Thanks for the hint,  I'm going to explore it.

Ok, it seems to me that I have found the cause - it was a hardware issue, my HDD crashed and I guess that problem with the error was just the precursor for that. Thanks a lot and sorry for bothering you.
